# Scrape multiple urls and pagination with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to call a predefined list of category urls. In each of these categories I must extract the data from the page, also go to the link on the next page and extract again.

I have this sample code, but something's missing:

```
import scrapy
import re

class YellowBot(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "yellow"
    allowed_domains = ["www.yellowpages.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.yellowpages.com/b/category1/',
        'http://www.yellowpages.com/b/category2/',
        'http://www.yellowpages.com/b/category3/',
        'http://www.yellowpages.com/b/category4/'
    ]
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.91 Safari/537.36'
    }



    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                headers=self.headers
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        self.logger.info('- page %s', response.url)
        ITEM_SELECTOR = 'ul.businesses li'
        SOURCE_TYPE = 'pages'
        for ficha in response.css(ITEM_SELECTOR):
            ficha = {
                'id'  : ficha.xpath('normalize-space(.//@data-bid)').extract_first(),
                'name'   : ficha.css('.business-name ::text').extract_first(),
                'description': ficha.xpath('.//div[@itemprop="description"]/text()').extract_first()
            }

            if ficha['id'] is not None:
                yield ficha

            next_page = response.css('.m-results-pagination li.last a::attr(href)').extract_first()
            if next_page is not None:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    response.urljoin(next_page),
                    headers=self.headers
                )
```

It extracts only the first category (also the following pages due to the pager):
http://www.yellowpages.com/b/category1/

But it does not process the next category page:
http://www.yellowpages.com/b/category2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following changes: `allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']`

and `yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)`. You should also state a `callback=self.parse` in your yielded requests for next pages.

Also, not sure about your start_urls. I tried inspecting the response using your selectors through `scrapy.shell` and `response.css('ul.businesses li')` returns an empty list.

Comment: it was that(callback).It was just an example domain. Thank you very much!